# What is a red-highlighted event in the timeline?

Tags: support, timeline

When I was new to the site, I always wondered what red-highlighted timeline events meant. Some events such as review events or audits are highlighted in red:

[image: Review Event]

What does the red highlight mean? Why are review items always shown as red?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Just like with posts, the red highlight means 'deleted'

For the case of review tasks, this means 'completed' or 'invalidated.' They were 'deleted' from the review queue, as they are no longer active. The reason why review events are always shown as red is because active review events are hidden from the history for some reason.

Other events can have the red background too, such as 'vote accept' events. These mean that an answer was previously accepted and then unaccepted:

[image: Deleted accept event]

But this red highlight meaning 'deleted' becomes apparent with moderator the tools privilege. Any 'answer added' event corresponding to a deleted answer will be hidden to <10K users, but will be shown as a red highlighted event to 10K+ users:

[image: Deleted answer]

All deleted events have 2 dates, the date they were 'created' and the date they were 'deleted.'